How to add a vent to the washer?
There is a pipe coming out of the floor and it's what the washer hose drains into.
Recently it started backing up. Had a plumber come out and he said it needs to be vented. Said he could add a p trap to what was already there and run a vent pipe. It doesn't have to run into the main stack of the house
For 500 dollars.
Can someone please tell me, if this pipe that's already here is the stand pipe or should I add a T fitting and attach a p trap with a stand pipe? And then run one up for a vent?
Please help! Thank you!!
